# Why Angular(2~5) is way faster than AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular

We all know `AngularJS` builds a digest loop when it comes to change detection , which proves to be less productive than `Angular`.

I want to know

1. **How** Angular works to get around this performance issue?
2. **Does Angular also have a digest loop similar mechanism**? if not , how does it know **when** a change could happen and need to perform change detection?
3. I know **Angular** boasts some features such as zone.js monkeypatch , unidirectional component tree, change detection strategy, RXJS ,immutableJS,etc..  either of which partly or directly drive **Angular** renders UI faster at the time a change happens. I'm not able to understand **how** `Angular` eventually gets faster by using these techniques together and properly?

Answer (score 5):

**Table that summarizes the major differences  between Angular and AngularJS  Change Detection.**
[image: AngularJS vs Angular CD]

**To Explore more on this**

1. **[Change Detection Differences between Angular and AngularJS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMkKzQmOnyg)**
2. **[Change Detection Reinvented Victor Savkin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvKGQSFQf10&t=2s)**
3. **[Angular’s $digest is reborn in the newer version of Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angulars-digest-is-reborn-in-the-newer-version-of-angular-718a961ebd3e)**
4. **[The Angular 2 Compiler Tobias Bosch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kW9cJsvcsGo&t=146s)**
5. **[The Angular Compiler 4.0 - TOBIAS BOSCH](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RXYjPYkFwy4).**

Comment: thanks, appreciate what you provided.